# Cannot stop Tfs 2010 Reporting Jobs

Tags: tfs

I have recently moved our TFS 2010 server to new server, when I'm trying to configure Reporting server and when I stop the reporting jobs the TFS tells me that there are running jobs please wait untill it is Idle.

[image: TFS Message when trying to edit reporting]

I wait for a long time till the jobs finish but no way, It is always running.

Any Ideas how can I stop the running jobs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the steps listed here? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsreporting/thread/44a81c42-1e24-4fcd-81d4-d864aebb7479/

HTH.
Cheers, Tarun

Comment: Oh no, i used steps listed here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869.aspx#StopServices when i moved my tfs server to another server. Have you tried restarting the service?

Comment: can i ask you to download http://rsjm.codeplex.com/ and see if the job is actually running. Ideally before the migration it is adviced to back up and First stop the Jobs in the TFS Administration Console and disable the Reporting. Then drop the Tfs_Analysis and Tfs_Warehouse databases. And last but not the least Go to the TFS Administration Console, enable and reconfigure and Reporting. This time, the TFS will recreate the Tfs_Analysis and Tfs_Warehouse databases.

Comment: Exactly the same issue you are facing. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsadmin/thread/9fa3a3b1-8c4a-400c-a19c-a29c2e0f21eb/

Comment: I tried this scenario, queued up a new request and then went to "tbl_JobQueue" table in "Tfs_Configuration" database and cleared the entry, and then i was able to proceed.

Comment: I've cleared the table "tbl_JobQueu" and it works now, Thank you Tarun :)